# Visual Studio Mac Os (Net Maui) "Workload ID maui is not recognized"

Tags: maui, .net-8.0, mac-catalyst

I am trying to run my Net Maui application developed in VS for windows on Mac as well (Maccatalyst). I get errors in VS for Mac when restoring packages for the project saying:

> error NETSDK1139: The target identifier maccatalyst was not
> recognized.

In terminal when I try to install the Net Maui workload by command:

> sudo dotnet workload install maui --source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

I get:

> Worload ID maui is not recognized

I have .Net 8.0.101 installed at /usr/local/Cellar/dotnet/8.0.1/libexec/sdk installed with homewbrew from command line.

Pointed Visual studio for MAC to this location and finds the Sdks.
MAC OS version is Sonoma 14.3
Xcode version is 15.2

Any ideas please?

Comment: Make sure your version of the .NET SDK is up to date, try reinstalling the .NET MAUI workload and make sure you use the correct workload ID.Check the location of the .NET SDK in Visual Studio for Mac to make sure you have selected the correct version and restart Visual Studio.If the problem persists, consider uninstalling and reinstalling the NET SDK.