# Getting 'Workload ID maui is not recognized' error when attempting to install .NET Maui

Tags: .net, maui

Below is the error I am getting in the terminal.

-MacBook-Air ~ % dotnet workload install maui

Workload ID maui is not recognized.

-MacBook-Air ~ % dotnet --version

8.0.101

How can I resolve?  I've noticed that the .Net webpage is offering version 8.0.2 but brew will only install up to 8.0.101.  Is my issue related to that?

Comment: You can refer to this similar issue:[Visual Studio Mac Os (Net Maui) "Workload ID maui is not recognized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77882872/visual-studio-mac-os-net-maui-workload-id-maui-is-not-recognized).